# react hoc for checkbox and radio component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm building my own checkbox and radio component, so that I can reuse it over and over again.

It will be something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class Checkbox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type={this.props.type === 'checkbox' ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'} placeholder={this.props.label} />
        )
    }
}
```

I can use it like this if I want a "checkbox"
`<Checkbox type="checkbox" label="My checkbox" />`

I can use it like this if I want a "checkbox"
`<Checkbox type="radio" label="My checkbox" />`

But how to improve above solution using HOC in this case? I got feedback of "create a higher order component that wraps the common component for each." from above implementation, does it even make sense to use HOC here? if HOC is a must requirement what will it looks like?

Comment: The only thing you're doing here is changing the type based on props. For a use case as simple as this, your implementation is just fine.

Comment: @vahissan what if I have other many props, if it must be a HOC, how would I do it?

Comment: I think you're confused about HoCs.. they don't make passing many props easier. Furthermore, HoCs aren't an improvement by themselves.. in fact the trend of HoCs is starting to fade away

Comment: @Melissa94 I really don't see why you need HOC for this example. If you give me another use case, I might be able to give you an example.

Comment: @azium not sure. Maybe I'm confused. But do you think it make sense to have wrapper.js, checkbox.js and radio.js implementation? or just one checkbox.js (which is my above's implementation)

Comment: Without seeing your code and how you intend to use it, there's no way to tell you if it will be a good implementation or not. Personally I would just use `<input />` instead of make a bunch of extra components

Comment: You're example is no more reusable than `input`

Comment: @azium there is no more code, imagine I need checkbox and radio, what's the HOC way to do it? and why? My colleague said it needs to be HOC, but I don't see much sense for that, coz it's just a prop different, which is the type (checkbox /  radio)

Comment: tell your colleague that's ridiculous and to stop over-engineering things. It doesn't even sound like they know what an HOC is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create HOC. You're simply returning input element. But HOCs are used like mixin:

```
const NewComponent = (BaseComponent) => {
  // ... create new component from old one and update
  return UpdatedComponent
}
```

See this [blog source](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-react-higher-order-components-by-example-95e8c47c8006) to understand HOC better.

---

To improve your component a little better, you can do just like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export class Checkbox extends Component {
    render() {
      const { type, label } = this.props
        return (
            <input type={type} placeholder={label} />
        )
    }
}
```

Now, you can simply pass type and label as required:

```
<Checkbox type="radio" label="The label" />
<Checkbox type="checkbox" label="The label" />
```

Or, if you want to use `checkbox` by default, then you can define the defaults like this:

```
Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  type: 'checkbox',
  label: 'The default label'
}
```

Now, if you use the component just like this:

```
<Checkbox />
```

This will render `<input type="checkbox" label="The default label" />`.

For more information on default props, see the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values).