# Applying className based on criteria match

Tags: reactjs

Basically I'm trying to see if the rating matches certain criteria then apply certain styles to each star in the list. Problem i'm running into is that only `twoStar` gets applied to all the list of stars className. How do I apply classname based on criteria match.

```
const starCluster = <div><FaStar /><FaStar /><FaStar /></div>

const starColor = (props) => {

  props.stardata.forEach((f, i) => {
    if (f.rating > 1 && f.rating <= 1.9) {
      return starColor = <div className="oneStar">{ starCluster }</div>
    }
    if (f.rating >=2 && f.rating <= 2.9) {
      return starColor = <div className="twoStar">{ starCluster }</div>
    }
  })

 return (
   <div> 
    <ul> 
    { 
      props.stardata.map((sta, i) => {
        return <div key={i}>
          <li >
            {sta.name}
            {starColor}
          </li>
        </div>
      }
    }
    </ul>
   </div>
}
```

edit:props.stardata is this way

```
[{name: "sirius", rating: 1.4}, {name: "polaris", rating: 2.4}, {name: "algol", rating: 3.6}]
```

Comment: See my today's [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868856/react-hoc-for-checkbox-and-radio-component/51869166#51869166) which will help you solving your problem.

Comment: Could you also add a sample of the `props.stardata`? Thanks

Comment: added props.stardata

Answer (score 1):

If you can add npm packages, I would highly recommend the [classNames npm package](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#readme), which greatly simplifies conditional class names.

You can basically pass in an object, where if the value is true, its key gets added as a className.

**Example:**

```
<div className=(classNames{
  key1: true,
  key2: false,
  key3: 3 > 2,
  key4: 5 < 1
}) />
```

Would render:

```
<div className="key1 key3" />
```

because the values for `key1` and `key3` return `true` in the `classNames` object.

**In your case:**

After `npm install classnames --save`, you can do:

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

const starCluster = <div><FaStar /><FaStar /><FaStar /></div>

const starColor = (props) => (
  <div> 
    <ul> 
    { 
      props.stardata.map((sta, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <li>
            {sta.name}
            <div className={classNames(
              oneStar: sta.rating > 1 && sta.rating <= 1.9,
              twoStar: sta.rating >= 2 && sta.rating <= 2.9
            )}>{ starCluster }</div>
          </li>
        </div>
      );
    }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below updated code

```
const starCluster = <div><FaStar /><FaStar /><FaStar /></div>

const starColor = (props) => {
  let rows = [];
  let starClr = "";
  props.stardata.map((sta, i) => {
        if (sta.rating > 1 && sta.rating <= 1.9) {
          starClr = <div className="oneStar">{ starCluster }</div>;
        }

        if (sta.rating >=2 && sta.rating <= 2.9) {
          starClr = <div className="twoStar">{ starCluster }</div>
        }
        rows.push(<li key={i}>
            {sta.name}
            {starClr}
          </li>)
      });

 return (
   <div> 
    <ul> 
    {rows}
    </ul>
   </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classnames 
npm install classnames --save

```
props.stardata.map((sta, i) => {
 starColor = <div className={classNames({'oneStar',f.rating>1&&f.rating<=1.9}, 
 {'twoStar',f.rating>=2&&f.rating<=2.9})}></div>
 rows.push(<li key={i}>
 {sta.name}
 {starColor}
 </li>)
});
```

The way it work is that you have to pass it object {class-U-want:condition-U-want}.It will set all that class-u-want as className which as full fill the condition (true)

```
<div className={classNames({'danger':true},{'noDanger':false})}>
</div>
```

is equal to

```
<div className='danger'>
</div>
```